# Ant script to modify a jar

Tags: ant, scripting, jar

Is there a way I can modify a file in a jar using ant script. Like, I have a x.properties in a y.jar. I want to edit this x.properties and put it back into the y.jar using ant script. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

`jar -xvf <filename>` extracts a file out of a jar.

`jar -uvf <filename>` can update a file in the jar.

You can use a script to do this and then use Ant to call the script.

Answer (score 0):

I usually unpack the whole jar file, alter the file I want to alter, and then create a new jar file. I is probably not the fasted way, but my build scrips are not time critical.